# Ckeditor Inline Dynamically modifying the toolbar for contenteditable

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor inline for my contenteditable div.

The HTML looks like

```
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

I would like to change the buttons in toolbar on button click.I call following function to change the toolbar

```
function changeToolBar(){
  var myToolBar = [{ name: 'verticalCustomToolbar', groups: [ 'basicstyles'], items: [ 'Blockquote'] }];
 var config = {};
 config.toolbar = myToolBar;
 CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
 CKEDITOR.replace('content', config);       

}
```

This one does not seem to work.

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RKPYw/17/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the code to following

```
function changeToolBar() {
 var myToolBar = [{ name: 'verticalCustomToolbar', groups: [ 'basicstyles'], items: [ 'Bold'] }];
 var config = {};
 config.toolbar = myToolBar;
 CKEDITOR.instances.test.destroy();//destroy the existing editor
 CKEDITOR.inline('test', config);      
}
```

The **CKEditor.inline** function expects the **id** of the element

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RKPYw/18/

Comment: Just to add, you can also feed `.inline()` a reference to the DOM object.